# Can't understand a step in the advanced calculus book by thomas P. Dence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

On page 9 of the Advanced calculus book by Thomas P. Dence he defines the set $S_1 = \{x\in \Bbb Q: x\geq 0, x^2 \leq 5\}$

and he said that the supremum $U$ is less than $u=3$ and that $U$ is nonnegative

and then he said that $$x= \frac{3U+5}{3+U}$$
I don't understand how we reached this final step

Comment: As it is, $S_1=\{0\}$.

Comment: Should the equation in question be $U=\frac{3U+5}{3+U}$?  This would give $U=\sqrt{5}$ which is the supremum of the given set (in the real numbers).

Comment: @paw88789 I think the OP committed a typo.

Comment: [Mary Star](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/80708/mary-star) [changed](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/864656/revisions) the OPs initial post which would make my comment true.

Comment: I'm not sure what the book is doing, but we have $U^2 = \sqrt{5}$, and so $3U+U^2 = 3U+5$ from which we have $U = { 3U+5 \over 3+U}$ and so $x \le { 3U+5 \over 3+U}$ for all $x \in S_1$. But again, I don't see the utility of this...

Comment: Whatever else is going on, this sort of maybe-it's-a-rabbit-out-of-hat style argument is idiotic and unexplanatory. Very popular, though, among the crowd that think's math is about pranking other people. The questioner is more-than-right to take some umbrage at this.

Comment: The short answer: $x$ is *defined* to be $(3U+5)/(3+U)$. When you introduce a new variable into a proof, you can define it to be whatever you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The author is asking you to assume that $U$ is the supremum of $S_1$ and is also a member of $S_1$, which means it is rational. He then ask you to suppose the following equation is true: $$x= \frac{3U+5}{3+U}$$

At this point, $x$ is just any variable; not necessarily a member of $S_1$ yet. The equation seems to come from nowhere but the author knows where he's going with it. Sometimes proofs are done this way. Read the rest of his argument and it might make sense. He's trying to show that the supremum of $S_1$ is not a member of $S_1$.